# Get column value from html string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting a response from a server on an html string similar to the following. Note that there is always **one** data row:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geoserver GetFeatureInfo output</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="featureInfo">
        <caption class="featureInfo">CATAST_Pol_ParcelaRusti</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>fid</th>
            <th >FEATURE</th>
            <th >REFCAT</th>
            <th >CMUNICIPIO</th>
            <th >MUNICIPIO</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CATAST_Pol_ParcelaRusti.109</td>    
            <td>200007</td>
            <td>1010232</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>ABÁIGAR</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Is there a way for programmatically get the `REFCAT` value (`=1010232`)
>   from the html string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is always one data row @User863

Comment: Have a look at the nextSibling

Comment: If you use JQuery this kind of access is very much easier, without JQuery, you could give each td tag an id which identifies its row and column, e.g. id="r1c3" if r is base 0.  Then its simple enough: document.getElementByID("r1c3");

Comment: Have a look at the DOM transversal functions on Javascript eg. childNodes and nextSibling something like: var TRARR=document.getElementByID("featureInfo").childNodes; TDARR=TRARR[2].childNodes; console.log(TDARR[2].innerText);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cellIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement#Properties)

```js
let th = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.featureInfo th'))
  .find(el => el.innerText === 'REFCAT')
  
let td = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.featureInfo td'))
  .find(el => el.cellIndex === th.cellIndex)

console.log(td.innerText)
```

```html
<table class="featureInfo">
  <caption class="featureInfo">CATAST_Pol_ParcelaRusti</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>fid</th>
    <th>FEATURE</th>
    <th>REFCAT</th>
    <th>CMUNICIPIO</th>
    <th>MUNICIPIO</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CATAST_Pol_ParcelaRusti.109</td>
    <td>200007</td>
    <td>1010232</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>ABÁIGAR</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```